# How to combine categorical data into different group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
        TermReason       Termcount
1     Another position      20
2        unhappy            14
3       more money          11
4     career change         9
```

I want to combine `Another position` & `career change` into `Better oppotinutity` and also sum up their numerical data, so does the other tow columns.

I would like to know how to make dataframe like this:

```
        Termgroup              Termcount
1   Better oppotinutity           29
2   Unsatisfied with job          25
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are defined categories? Another position & career change into Better oppotinutity and all another words are `Unsatisfied with job` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary defined groups, here I use dictionary of lists, then mapping column `TermReason` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with flatten dictionary `d1` and last aggregate `sum`:

```
d = {'Better oppotinutity':['Another position','career change'],
     'Unsatisfied with job':['unhappy','more money']}

d1 = {x: k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
df['Termgroup'] = df['TermReason'].map(d1)
print (df)
         TermReason  Termcount             Termgroup
1  Another position         20   Better oppotinutity
2           unhappy         14  Unsatisfied with job
3        more money         11  Unsatisfied with job
4     career change          9   Better oppotinutity

df = df.groupby('Termgroup', as_index=False)['Termcount'].sum()
print (df)
              Termgroup  Termcount
0   Better oppotinutity         29
1  Unsatisfied with job         25
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the original dataframe is `df`, the following will do the work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['Termgroup'] = np.where(df['TermReason'].isin(['Another position', 'career change']), 'Better oppotinutity', 'Unsatisfied with job')
df = df.groupby('Termgroup').sum().reset_index()

[Out]:

              Termgroup  Termcount
0   Better oppotinutity         29
1  Unsatisfied with job         25
```

---

Let's break down each step.

Let us create a new column to store `Better oppotinutity` when one has `Another position` or `career change`, else use `Unsatisfied with job`. For that, one will use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) as follows

```
df['Termgroup'] = np.where(df['TermReason'].isin(['Another position', 'career change']), 'Better oppotinutity', 'Unsatisfied with job')

[Out]:

         TermReason  Termcount             Termgroup
0  Another position         20   Better oppotinutity
1     career change          9   Better oppotinutity
2        more money         11  Unsatisfied with job
3           unhappy         14  Unsatisfied with job
```

Finally, with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), `.sum()` and [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) one will be able to get the desired output

```
df = df.groupby('Termgroup').sum().reset_index()

[Out]:

              Termgroup  Termcount
0   Better oppotinutity         29
1  Unsatisfied with job         25
```